# qbXMLRP2e not being registered

Tags: quickbooks

I installed [QB SDK  v12](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb/0020_Get_Set_Up/SDK_Downloads)

Then I tried to register the COM object as follows:

```
qbXMLRP2e.exe \regserver
```

When I go to view the DCOM objects it is not there. How can I register the COM object so I can edit the security properties to give asp.net access?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall it and re-install it as administrator. Then it showed up under the DCOM objects.